# How do I ge the values from input type="Text" and then average it using js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the average from input type="text". In the input type text, it has the format 1,2,3. When they click on the button it should alert them the average. Here is my code:

In the input type text in the snippet type in 1,2,3. Then you will see the problem.

```js
function averagevalue(){
var numberstouse = document.getElementById('average').value;
const average = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;
alert(average([numberstouse]));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="average" value>
<button type="btn" onclick="averagevalue()">Avg</button>
```

But the problem is, as you can see in the snippet, it says the value NaN. But in the alert, I want to says the average. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert the input to an array

> The split() method takes a pattern and divides a String into an
> ordered list of substrings by searching for the pattern, puts these
> substrings into an array, and returns the array.

```js
function averagevalue(){
var numberstouse = document.getElementById('average').value;
const average = array => array.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b)) / array.length;
alert(average(numberstouse.split(',')));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="average" value=>
<button type="btn" onclick="averagevalue()">Avg</button>
```

Comment: You haven't just used split.

Comment: Sorry, I mean may you also add an explanation of converting the string values to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The value is a comma seperated string. so we use the `.split()` method on it with, `,` as an argument to that method and that will return a list without the comma.

Edit : I forgot to convert the items in list to number. fixed !

```js
function averagevalue(){
var numberstouse = document.getElementById('average').value;
numberstouse = numberstouse.split(',')
numberstouse = numberstouse.map(str => Number(str));
const average = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length
alert(average(numberstouse));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="average" value=>
<button type="btn" onclick="averagevalue()">Avg</button>
```

Comment: This outputs `41`

Comment: should be fixed now. I forgot to convert the items that are in the list to type number.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the whole input and split it to make a new array, and its elements to floats
you could use this instead :

```
function averagevalue(){
var numberstouse = document.getElementById('average').value;
const average = numberstouse =>
{
    let newArr = numberstouse.split(",");
    let val = newArr.reduce((a,b)=>parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b)) / newArr.length;
    return val;
} 
alert(average(numberstouse));
}
```